# Is quantum state simply a linear combination of classical states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Classically, a Bit can be in the 0-state or the 1-state. But a Qubit is in a linear combination of these two states:

$$|\psi \rangle = \alpha |0 \rangle + \beta |1 \rangle$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two complex numbers.

Classically, a particle can have only one location in space. But in QM, a particle is in a linear combination of all possible locations in space; this linear combination is called its wavefunction $|\psi\rangle$, and similar to the Qubit case, the wavefunction is formed by assigning a complex number to each location in space.

These examples lead me to think that the Quantum state of a system is simply formed by assigning a complex number to each of its Classical states, and then adding them together. Thus, am I right in saying that:

```
The quantum state of a system is simply the superposition (linear combination) of its classical states?
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily make sense in *every* case, but since you can always write your wavefunction as a linear combination of the eigenstates of each Hermitian operator corresponding to an observable, and since the eigenstates tend to individually resemble classical states, this is (at least in spirit, not in a precise sense) not an entirely unreasonable way of putting it.

Comment: Although in a more precise sense, classical states are points in a manifold whereas in quantum mechanics they are elements of a Hilbert space (usually). Which is why I say it sort of works at a very heuristic level, not a technical one.

Comment: Very insightful answer... Thanks Charlie!

Comment: Wouldn't classical states be coherent states? Which tbf are linear combinations of the eigenfunctions.

Comment: I am actually an amateur physicist, so I don't know what coherent states are... 